Which command installs React and what is the difference?
Which of these commands installs React and what is the difference between them? npm i react react-dom or npm install -g create-react-app?
I searched blogs and documentation, but I still can't resolve this question.

Do you already have a project, and you're trying to add react to it? Or are you trying to make a brand new project?

I would just like to know the difference between these commands and which one to use. Nicholas tower

npm i react react-dom adds the packages to an existing project, create-react-app is a tool (not necessarily the best tool these days) for creating a project. I recommend you check out react's documentation on starting a project, and their documentation on adding react to an existing project.

The one that installs React is the one that installs React, rather than Create React App. The difference is which package(s) they install, and where (local vs. global).

The command npm i react react-dom just installs React as a dependency. You will need to create an application based on React from line zero without having any files pre-generated.
For npm install -g create-react-app, things are a bit different. This command is deprecated, but it used to install Create React App, which is a command-line application to quickly create a new React app based on a minimal, but functional demo application that you can use as a base for your own application. It will pre-generate some basic files for a React app, such as a component, the package.json file, etc.
As the second command is deprecated, it is replaced by npx create-react-app my-app. This will not install Create React App permanently, but just run it once to create a new React project (called my-app).
Short: If you want to create a new React project in a fast and easy way, npx create-react-app my-app (while replacing my-app with the name of your project) is the way to go. See the Create React App docs for more details.

I understand, but if I want to install react on my machine, which command do I use?

@viniideveloper you don't really install React on your machine such as installing Node.js or something similar globally. React is a dependency of your project, so it's installed once per project. For example, if you develop 5 different applications using React on your machine, you'll have 5 installations of React, one per project. To create a new project template, the npx create-react-app my-app command, and for adding to to an existing project, use npm i react react-dom.
